# zsh command not found error when setting an alias

Tags: bash, macos, command, alias, aws-cli

Currently trying to move all of my aliases from .bash_profile to .zshrc. However, found a problem with one of the longer aliases I use for substituting root to ubuntu when passing a command to access AWS instances.

```
AWS (){                                                                          
    cd /Users/user/aws_keys                                                                          
    cmd=$(echo $@ | sed "s/root/ubuntu/g")                                                                                                        
    $cmd[@]                                                                      
}
```

The error I get is `AWS:5: command not found ssh -i keypair.pem ubuntu@ec1.compute.amazonaws.com`

I would really appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: please update the question with additional details, eg, the actual `AWS ...` call, the value of `$@`, the contents of `cmd`, and what you think `$cmd[@]` should translate to (ie, what is the actual command you think should be executed); assuming this works in `bash` it might be of interest if you provide these same details for both `bash` and `zsh` in order to highlight where the difference(s) is occurring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is that the `cmd=$(echo ...` line is mashing all the arguments together into a space-delimited string, and you're depending on word-splitting to split it up into a command and its arguments. But word-splitting is usually more of a problem than anything else, so zsh doesn't do it by default. This means that rather than trying to run the command named `ssh` with arguments `-i`, `keypair.pem`, etc, it's treating the entire string as the command name.

The simple solution is to avoid mashing the arguments together, so you don't need word-splitting to separate them out again. You can use a modifier to the parameter expansion to replace "root" with "ubuntu". BTW, I also strongly recommend checking for error when using `cd`, and not proceeding if it gets an error.

So something like this:

```
AWS (){
    cd /Users/user/aws_keys  || return $?
    "${@//root/ubuntu}"
}
```

This syntax will work in bash as well as zsh (the double-quotes prevent unexpected word-splitting in bash, and aren't really needed in zsh).

BTW, I'm also a bit nervous about just blindly replacing "root" with "ubuntu" in the arguments; what if it occurs somewhere other than the username, like as part of a filename or hostname?

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me. Also thank you for bringing your concern about blindly replacing root with ubuntu. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: @Blue_K It occurs to me that you could cut down on the probability of bad substitutions with `"${@/root@/ubuntu@}"` -- it'll only replace if it ends with "@", and only once per argument (because of just one `/` before the substitution).

Comment: Thank u for the suggestion!